# Looping and composing an array with MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I was wondering if it were possible to give multiple string values to a single key in a mongo document? I'm connecting mongo with a python flak app and I'm running into some frustrating difficultlies. I'll explain myself better here:

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "5c0c0843e7179a2e2704fe86"
},
"category_name": "Breakfast",
"recipe_name": "Scambled Egg",
"recipe_ingredients": [
"Eggs",
"1/4 cup of Milk",
"2 tsp. Butter"
],
"recipe_servings": 2,
"recipe_author": "Sally Reynolds",
"recipe_calories": 192,
"recipe_country_of_origin": "England",
"step_one": "BEAT eggs, milk, salt and pepper in medium bowl until blended., HEAT butter in large nonstick skillet over medium heat until hot. POUR IN egg mixture, GENTLY PULL the eggs across the pan with a spatula, forming large soft curds.",
"prep_time": "1 Minute",
"cooking_time": "4 Minutes",
"vegan": "false"enter 
}
```

In recipe_ingredients, is it possible to include all three of these strings without getting this response on the browser:

```
[u'Eggs', u'1/4 cup of Milk', u'2 tsp. Butter']
```

I just want to display these three items

Comment: Couldn't you make a list of strings, and add that under a key

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Sure. `.insert(['1 string', 'A second string'])`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really confused about this. I understand strings and arrays but I'm finding the JSON syntax really difficult to loop through. I'm just unsure where to put that .insert. If a key has one value I'm fine but anymore and I crumble. I've never been shown how to add more than one and still have it work through a python ginja. My ginja for this is {{recipe.recipe_ingredients}}